# string in range is not working

Tags: python, int, range

I'm new to Python. I'm struggling with range. I'm not good at explaining this problem but I will show you a problem.

Here my code:

```
my_hanes = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Grey', 'Black']
my_hanes_len = len(my_hanes)
for h in range(0, my_hanes_len):
   print(my_hanes_len[h])
```

Every time, the message pop up and said "'int' object is not subscriptable"

How do you solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Because you are trying to access your list using `my_hanes_len`. I think you actually want to use `my_hanes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `print(my_hanes[h])` instead of `print(my_hanes_len[h])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each object of a list more simply, as you're trying to do

```
my_hanes = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Grey', 'Black']
for hanes in my_hanes:
    print hanes
```

This will print each item in list `my_hanes`.

Comment: Lists in Python **are accessible through indices**, and **they are sortable** too - it's just direct iteration is preferred.Your code is right, but your explanation is totally off target.

Comment: Removed that portion - cannot recall which object I confused with lists that is unsortable..

Comment: Sets and dictionaries are **unordered**, not un-sortable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that my_hanes is an array of strings.  So len(my_hanes) is an integer value (4) indicating the length of your array (aka python list).  If you want to get the length of each element of my_hanes as a list, you can iterate to make one:

```
my_hanes = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Grey', 'Black']
my_hanes_len = list()
for hanes in my_hanes:
    my_hanes_len.append(len(hanes))
print(my_hanes_len)
```

Comment: As a note on python conventions, it's also generally preferable to iterate over items in a list as shown rather than index iterating if the index isn't explicitly needed.